# How to use bundler with dojo in .Net MVC4

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, dojo

In my _Layout.cshtml page this is how I have referenced the dojo files

```
<script>
        dojoConfig.addModuleName(
                "abc/widget/forms/view/acss/travelDocuments/Warning",
                "abc/widget/forms/view/acss/travelDocuments/RequiredFieldError"
        );
</script>
```

How do I create the bundle in Bundle Config so as to include the dojo files.

I have tried the following approach

In BundleConfig.cs I used the following code

```
 bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/mobilejs").Include(
                "~/js/abc/widget/forms/view/acss/travelDocuments/Warning",
                "~/js/abc/widget/forms/view/acss/travelDocuments/RequiredFieldError",
                ));
```

In _Layout.cshtml page I used the following code

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        var dojoConfig = {
            async: true,
            parseOnLoad: true,
            addModuleName: ("abc/widget/forms/view/acss/travelDocuments/Warning",
                "abc/widget/forms/view/acss/travelDocuments/RequiredFieldError"
               )
        }
  </script>
```

But the above code failed to load the dojo files.

Any suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where you are loading the dojo core files in your bundle, but it has to be **after** the dojoConfig declaration.